# Get shown component in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, scrollpane

I have a JScrollPane containing a JPanel. I fill this JPanel with many buttons.

Is there any possibility to get the currently shown buttons?

I know I can access the children of a JPanel via `jpanel.getComponents()` but those are all components in this pane; I want only the ones that are currently on screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that this container is already visible on the screen, then I suggest

1) to extract [JViewPort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) from [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html),

2) [addChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) to `JViewPort`

3) each visible `JComponent(s)` returns [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

4) and [Rectangle#intersects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) returns `Boolean` value if is `JComponent(s)` visible or not in `JViewPort`

Comment: enjoying detours, don't you :-) nothing of that is needed, except bullet 3 and the first part of bullet 4 ...

Answer (score 9):

As already commented to @mKorbel's answer:

- it's correct that you need the child bounds
- it's correct that you need to intersect those bounds with "something"
- it's *wrong* that you need the containing viewport (nor the scrollpane)

JComponents have an API to get their currently visible part independently of how/where exactly they are currently shown, so the "something" is the JComponent's visibleRect:

```
Rectangle visibleRect = myPanel.getVisibleRect();
for (Component child : myPanel.getComponents()) {
   Rectangle childBounds = child.getBounds();
   if (childBounds.intersects(visibleRect)) {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer. I was surprised to find it on the bottom!

Comment: c) `it's wrong that you need the containing viewport (nor the scrollpane)`,  [not you can to use reshape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#reshape%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), then `JViewport` can returns different `Rectangle` as came /delegated from/by `JScrollPane`

Comment: @mKorbel Sunday morning head-scratching - as so often I don't quite understand what you are saying :-) Where in my code do you see a viewport? It not being there is the whole point: it doesn't matter who is the parent, internals will take of the nitty details.

Comment: So there's no callback available somwhere to get notified when components are getting hidden by the scroll pane? Looping through all components each time it scolls sounds inefficient... (PS: +1 :-))

Comment: @Matthieu didn't lay my hands on swing for a while, but afaik there isn't any api. If you really need it (can't imagine a use-case) you might implement a custom component that keeps track of the "showing" state of its children, and fires some notification whenever that state changes. JViewPort might be good for starters, but is a nasty one iirc ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I was afraid you would reply that ;) A use case would be triggering a load when components of a scroll pane are shown (a few out of several thousand) and freeing that memory when those components scroll beyond visibility.

Answer (score 1):

How about asking the components if they're visible:

```
for ( Component component : jpanel.getComponents() ) {
    if ( component instanceof JButton && component.isShowing() ) {
        // We've found a button that is showing...
    }
}
```

- [`Component#isShowing()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing%28%29)

Comment: this will not work becouse if i scroll the scrollpane there are components that are currently not visible the function isShowing will for every component return true even if there are not visible for the user... sry

Comment: simply wrong - the OP clearly stated "not all .. [but only] currently on screen" (okay, maybe slightly misunderstandable :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollPane.getViewport().getView()
scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect()
```

Comment: too complicated .. and _you_ know it :-)

Comment: Please add proper comment to your code. Code without comment has no value to author of question.